# using python subprocess.call to kill all running python files

Tags: python, kill, subprocess

I'm trying to kill (on a demand) all the python processes that are running at the moment.
I was using this command:

```
from subprocess import call  
call('pkill python', shell=True)  
print 'Killed them all!'
```

But, of course - my program is also a python program, so eventually, it doesn't reach the print line after calling 'call'.

What can I do in order to avoid my program to kill also itself, while killing all other python processes?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to try cross-platform [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) library:

```
import os
import psutil

mypid = os.getpid()
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name == 'python' and proc.pid != mypid:
        proc.kill()
```

Comment: do I have to install anything? It says: 'No module named psutil'

Comment: Sure you do. Check out [Downloads](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/downloads/list) or `pip install psutil` or `apt-get install python-psutil`.

Answer (score 0):

If you call out to `pgrep python` you'll be able to read in the pids (process identifiers) of all the running python processes. You'll probably want `subprocess.check_output` for this.

Then you can run through the pids killing each (using `os.kill`) except for the one that matches your own pid, which you find using `os.getpid`.

Comment: It says to me: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output' --> What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may be using an older version of python. However @bereal's solution is neater.