# Python: killall processes by name except itself

Tags: python

I want my Python Script to kill all instances of Python except itself. E.g. if its PID is 87457, something like

```
killall -9 python -except 87457
```

lg, couka

Comment: possible duplicate of [using python subprocess.call to kill all running python files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654784/using-python-subprocess-call-to-kill-all-running-python-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to *cook* up something in order to achieve that.  Something like the following should work:

```
ps auxw | grep [p]ython | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v 87457 | xargs kill -9
```

You might create a shell function for the same:

```
killpy() {
  ps auxw | grep [p]ython | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v $1 | xargs kill -9
}
```

and invoke it by saying:

```
killpy 87457
```